# How to add a free task installed from market in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I raised a request for GitTools task in Azure Devops and now I can see that in my organization extensions setting tab.

[image: Organization Extension Tab in Azure DevOps]

But now when I want to add this to my pipeline, I am not seeing any Add button.

[image: Add installed task from the market place to Azure pipeline]

I am able to add other tasks such as Yarn or Replace Tokens(See the first image, below GitTools Task).

Below you can see Add button is enabled. But for GitTools, I dont see any Add button. What am I missing?

[image: Add Yarn task to Azure DevOps pipeline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use `Execute GitVersion Task` and `Setup GitVersion Task` tasks. Search with `GitVersion` pattern:

[image]